# Why should i discard carry out in adding binary numbers?

Tags: assembly, binary, computer-science, cpu-architecture

[image]

for example,for 8 bit number.
why should i discard this 1?
I understood that overflow is only when im adding 2 numbers in same sign and get a result in the other sign.Whats the case here?

Comment: what do you mean discard the 1?  the answer is `1000 1111` which is what you have...it looks like you forgot to hold the third place in with a `0` (result of `1 + 1`)

Comment: ok im sorry,i will have to correct my example:

Comment: The example isn't broken, but it *looks* broken, since the left 3 result digits aren't below the corresponding input digits.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are you asking? Are you asking why the carry out of the top bit doesn't really matter in a signed interpretation?

Comment: @harold I mean why is that correct to discard the 1 after the last add

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you want to know..

Comment: what is that correct to discard this 1 after the last add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wouldn't *want* to discard it, but typically you *have* to because the word size is limited, and you cannot work with larger numbers. That is why in many languages having the carry bit set after an addition is treated as an overflow error.

Comment: so is my example has overflow?

Comment: Yes, because the result of the addition cannot be represented in the size of the output type.

Comment: but the result is correct..so why is that an oveflow?

Comment: Because that bit cannot be stored in a machine word, and normally gets discarded.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using unsigned bytes, the first number (0101.1101) is 93, and the second one (1101.1011) is 219. The result, 312, is too large to fit into an (8-bit) integer. There's no way to fix this except using more bits, for instance 16, where the result, 1.0011.1000 has a representation.

If you're using signed bytes, the first number stays 93, but the second is -37. So the result should be 56, which is correct *without* the leading 1. So, ignoring the overflow bit is the correct thing to do in this case. However, if you wanted to keep the overflow bit, and used 16 bit numbers, you'd have to fill the negative numbers with 1- bits from the left, resulting in 1111.1111.1101.1011. Which would again mean when adding them you have an overflow bit.

Bottom line: Adding two binary numbers of the same bit size returns the correct result, even if you ignore the overflow bit, if there's a way to represent that result with the given number of bits.

Comment: im using 2's complement.MY question is what is that right to discard this 1?

Comment: You can't answer that question unless you decide whether to treat your values as signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Anton, 8 bits is 8 bits there is no right or wrong about it you either have enough bits to store results or you dont.  2's complement is always used, the question is signed or unsigned, and unsigned or signed is in the eyes of the programmer the hardware (for addition and subtraction) doesnt know or care about signed or unsigned.

Answer (score -1):

I will use a simpler example to explain. 
We compute `A - B = 7 - 6 = 1`.

`A = 7 = 0111`

`B = 6 = 0110`

We use `B'` to denote the complement of `B`, then `B' = 1001`.
We know

`B + B' = 1111 = -1`

`-B = B'+ 1`        (`-6 = 1001 + 1 = 1010`)

Then we do

`|    0111`

`| +  1010`

`| = 10001`

Why we get a 1 for the highest bit??? Here's the reason:

`|    A - B = A + (-B)`

`|          = A + (B' + 1)`       <-- Use 2's complement method.

`|          = A + ((1111 - B) + 1)`  <-- Use the fact that `B + B' = 1111`.

`|          = A - B + (1111 + 1)`

`|          = A - B + 10000`    <-- That's where the highest 1 comes from. Because the equal sign, we know we can discard the highest 1 if needed.